# Normalization of histogram in OPENCV

Tags: histogram, normalization, opencv3.0

I have problem concerned around normalization process during OpenCV project. The function which I should use is called cvNormalizeHist, however I do not know about how to use it directly in code.

```
C: void cvNormalizeHist(CvHistogram* hist, double factor)

Parameters: 
    hist – Pointer to the histogram.
    factor – Normalization factor.

The function normalizes the histogram bins by scaling them so that the sum of the bins becomes equal to factor.
```

What I am trying to do is something like:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat src, dst;

    /// Load image
    src = imread(argv[1], 1);

    if (!src.data)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    /// Separate the image in 3 places ( B, G and R )
    vector<Mat> bgr_planes;
    split(src, bgr_planes);

    /// Establish the number of bins
    int histSize = 256;

    /// Set the ranges ( for B,G,R) )
    float range[] = { 0, 256 };
    const float* histRange = { range };

    bool uniform = true; 
    bool accumulate = false;

    Mat b_hist, g_hist, r_hist;

    /// Compute the histograms:
    calcHist(&bgr_planes[0], 1, 0, Mat(), b_hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate);
    calcHist(&bgr_planes[1], 1, 0, Mat(), g_hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate);
    calcHist(&bgr_planes[2], 1, 0, Mat(), r_hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate);

    cvNormalizeHist(b_hist, 5); // (1)

    CvHistogram histogram(); // (2)
    ...

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to use such a function, however the error suggest me that I should use CvHistogram instead of Mat object. And I do not know how to convert between those objects.

Anyone may give me how I can do it or any suggestions ?

More informations which may be useful are:
Windows 10, Visual Studio 2013, OpenCV 3.0

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid using obsolete C functions.

You can use [normalize](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga87eef7ee3970f86906d69a92cbf064bd), with `alpha` equals to your factor, and `NORM_L1`.

For example:

```
double factor = 25;
normalize(b_hist, b_hist, factor, 0, NORM_L1);

cout << sum(b_hist)[0];
```

You see that the sum of the bins becomes equal to factor.

Comment: However my teacher require test program with such a function. 
Any way to overgo this and satisfy his bullshits ?

Comment: Sorry for the comment above, however University approach is frustrating me since some time. It is utopia like a socialism.

Comment: Ok, I don't have time to update the answer with _obsolete_ code. But you can get an example [here](https://siddhantahuja.wordpress.com/2010/02/19/working-with-histograms-in-opencv-2/) on how to create a CvHistogram. You can then apply your function...

Comment: Thank you Miki, that should be sufficient for me. I was looking for something like this for a wihle through internet but could not find it. have a nice day :)